# Stop date dropping zero's

Tags: java, android

How do I stop the ints dropping the zeros in the time? I've tried formatting it with

```
String.format("%02d", minutes);
```

but it doesn't work, I'm sure it's quite simple!

```
Date dt = new Date();
int hours = dt.getHours();
int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes;
String.format("%02d", minutes);
updatedat.setText("Updated at " + curTime);
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `SimpleDateFormat`? And what do you expect calling `String.format("%02d", minutes)` to do when you're not using the result?

Comment: Oh, and please take note of the fact that `getHours` and `getMinutes` are both deprecated. You should be using `Calendar` - or ideally Joda Time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a SimpleDateFormat object instead to format dates/times.

```
Date date = new Date(); // initializes to current time
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
updatedat.setText("Updated at " + df.format(date));
```

Read more about SimpleDateFormat and the formatting specifications [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because `String.format("%02d", minutes);` is a function that returns a string

for your case if minutes was 8, `String.format("%02d", minutes);` would return `08`

So, for this to work you'd have to have something like:

```
String curTime = hours + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes);
```

I also agree that you shouldn't be formatting the time like this, use a date formatter.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of including 0's is to use a function like:

```
public String TwoCh(int i) { String s= "0" + Integer.toString(i); return s.substring(s.length() - 2); }
```

and then (notwithstanding the fact that getHours and getMinutes are both deprecated), you can do things like

```
String curTime = TwoCh(dt.getHours())+ ":" + TwoCh(dt.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to get the time in following format
22:01

In order to do that, use simpleDateFormat
you can read the full documentation, visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html